# Argument in $where Javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb

Consider the following code (coming from https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php) :

```
<?php

$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->selectDB('test');
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'phpmanual');

$js = "function() {
    return this.name == 'Joe' || this.age == 50;
}";
$cursor = $collection->find(array('$where' => $js));
foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
    var_dump($doc);
}

?>
```

Is it possible to pass an argument to the Javascript function defining $js ? If so, how ?

I try to but don't succeed.

KR

Comment: Why you need to pass any argument in the function, you are writing the whole definition if you want anything dynamic just write directly in definition

Answer (score 0):

This is called "code with scope", the PHP implementation of it is documented [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-javascript.php). Pass the variables as the second argument to the constructor.